# Idiomatic way to efficiently reinitialize/replace container element while recycling internals in modern C++?

Tags: stl, c++14, c++17

I am storing a custom image object type in a std::vector and treating the vector as a circular buffer. Each image has an overwrite(...) method to reinitialize it with new content (same dimensions) each time the buffer loops - my question is in 'modern' C++ (am already using C++17 for string_view) what is the idiomatic way of doing this?

Was thinking some combination of using vector.emplace() and an appropriate constructor on the image class. Or perhaps somehow using placement new.

Basically I would like to keep all my image initialization logic inside a constructor instead of split between constructor and overwrite() while avoiding the cost of destroying and initializing new internal buffers and such.

Comment: Just to clarify by 'new content' I only meant new values, in my application the image content is initialized from compressed data in constructor/overwrite() and as such the pixel memory needs to be acquired from somewhere as a destination for the new content to expand into.

Comment: Perhaps this article may help 
https://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/calling-constructors-with-placement-new/232901023?pgno=1

Answer (score 0):

You want to *move* the

> new content

to an existing entry in the vector, so a move assignment operator in your "custom image" class will help, e. g.:

```
class CustomImage
{
public:
    CustomImage() = default;
    CustomImage(std::vector<unsigned char>&& data)
        : data_(std::move(data))
    {}
    // move assignment
    CustomImage& operator=(CustomImage&&) = default;
private:
    // possible way of storing image data
    std::vector<unsigned char> data_;
};
```

Then you can move the new content to the ring buffer entry like so:

```
// initialize the ring buffer with 5 empty entries
std::vector<CustomImage> ring_buffer(5);
// some new example image
std::vector<unsigned char> first_image{2,4,5,7,9};
// move assign the new image to the current entry in the ring buffer
ring_buffer.at(0) = std::move(first_image);
```

This is modern (due to move semantics) and fast, because memory of the image is not copied.

Comment: By 'new content' I meant new values - which in this case are generated while expanding compressed image data during construction. As such although your solution avoids a waist full copy the constructor would still need to aqier a new chunk of memory  - ideally I need a way of passing the memory already being used by the destination to the new constructor to 'construct' into

Comment: Hm, seems like you want to keep the container of the data (i. e. your custom image object) in the buffer on the one hand (because the ring buffer's size shall not change I assume), but want to construct a new object (cite "I would like to keep all my image initialization logic inside a constructor") on the other hand. That sound contradictory to me. I would go for a "reset" method then, which is similar to many classes of stdlib, e. g. the std::shared_ptr which is a shell for a raw pointer. "reset"ting it just replaces the raw pointer (the uncompressed image data in your case).